# Hard drive corrupts when in use and appears as RAW after reboot

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, freeze, symbolic-link

At the moment all of my steamapps folder is on a separate drive connected via a symbolic link. Last week while in game the program crashed and would not quit, even after terminating from the Task Manager. So I restarted my computer.

After the restart the drive was showing in This PC (My Computer) however there was no indication of the size or size remaining. When I tried to access it Windows alerted me to format the drive before use. Uh oh. I checked Disk Management and the drive was showing as RAW and only at a capacity of about 32GB, even though it's 2TB (WD Green).

I turned it off again and unplugged the Sata cable, restarted again then rebooted with it plugged back in. Still the same. Did a quick Google and ran **bootrex /fixmbr**

Which seemed to work. Until it did the same a couple of days later. So I repeated the steps and got the drive to a position where I could backup everything from it. Then bought a new drive.

Thought this was the end of it until yesterday when the new drive 3TB WD Green started stalling in the middle of a game every 10-30 seconds. After exiting the game and restarting the new drive again showed up in This PC but wasn't accessible. Unfortunately my methods of "repairing" the problem didn't work this time, however I did manage to find a program to recover the data from the RAW file system.

I have no idea what is causing this and would like to prevent it from happening again if anyone could shed some light on this

Comment: Why are you fixing the MBR on the non-system disk? The problem seems to be connected to these Green hdds you are purchasing, have you modified the power settings, so they don't turn themselfs off randomly?

Comment: The site I found whilst Googling system fixing the MBR. I haven't tried modifying the power settings as it didn't seem to be turning it self off rather than just freezing. The initial 2TB drive was running without problem for 2 years

Comment: Let me put it this way.  Its not normal for even a green energy drive to lose its file system, even if it turned itself off, while data was being written to it.  I actually would consider the drive freezing an indication the drive is powering itself off.

Comment: That's quite worrying then. How would you suggest rectifying this problem? Do WD provide software to modify the power options?

Comment: I don't use these green drives unless they are being used as cold storage.  This means only writting data on demand.  A hdd shutting itself down, while writting data certainly is good for the file system, but for this to happen more then once indicates a configuration problem at the very least.  You normally can handle tell Windows what it can and cannot do with a power state of a device in `Device Manager` you might look there.